# ASP.NET MVC Button click on table row always returns first row (modal)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying, trying and trying but I don't come to a solution.. :(
It would be great if someone experienced could have a look into it.

My situation:

I have a table with multiple rows and one row with button(s). One if those are a "Cancel" button to delete the data record. In generel this is working perfectly but I implemented a modal dialog to ask the user before processing the cancel if he's really sure to cancel it.
Since I implemented the modal dialog, on the button click the selected row always changes to the first row and not the row where the user clicked on. So if the user clicks on the "Cancel" button in row 2, it shows the data of row 1 in the modal popup and also redirects the ID of row 1 to the controller.

My View:

```
@model ViewModels.ServicesViewModel

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>DB Name</th>
        <th>DB Description</th>
        <th>DB Version</th>
        <th>Access valid until</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.AssignedDatabases)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%">@item.DB_Name</td>
            <td style="width:35%">@item.DB_Description</td>
            <td style="width:10%">@item.DB_Version</td>
            <td style="width:15%">@item.ExpiryDate</td>
            <td style="width:20%">
                @if (item.RequestState.Equals("Open"))
                {
                    <a href="#"><i class="btn btn-info btn-md" style="font-family:Arial">Pending</i></a>
                }
                else
                {
                    <a href="#"><i data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" style="font-family:Arial">Cancel</i></a>
                }
                @if (Model.ResponsibleDBs.Exists(x => x.DB_UID == item.DB_UID))
                {
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Manage", new { id = item.DB_UID })"><i class="btn btn-success btn-md" style="font-family:Arial">Manage</i></a>
                }
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "AssignedDatabases", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <div id="exampleModal" class="modal" tabindex="3" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Do you really want to cancel the access to @item.DB_Name ?</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.DB_UID })"><i class="btn btn-success btn-md" style="font-family:Arial">Yes</i></a>
                                    <a href=""><i data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" style="font-family: Arial">No</i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a href="@Url.Action("RequestDatabase", "RequestDatabase")"><i class="btn btn-success btn-md" style="font-family:Arial">Request new</i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('body').on('click', 'a.modal-link', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $("#modal").remove();

            // Get the Details action URL
            var url = $(this).attr("href");

            //Make the Ajax call and render modal when response is available
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $(data).modal();
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

BR,
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes from the usage of the non-unique ID #exampleModal. Thus the browser always uses the first element with that ID.

If you want to leave the modal within the foreach loop, you should append something unique to the ID.

Answer (score 0):

@Niyak

You are the king! Thank you!
I added a unique identifier to the datatarget and modal and now its working.
So simple... Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees :)

Changed the code now to:

```
@model ViewModels.ServicesViewModel
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>DB Name</th>
        <th>DB Description</th>
        <th>DB Version</th>
        <th>Access valid until</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.AssignedDatabases)
    {
        var dataTargetCancel = "#ModalCancel" + item.DB_UID;
        var modalID = "ModalCancel" + item.DB_UID;

        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%">@item.DB_Name</td>
            <td style="width:35%">@item.DB_Description</td>
            <td style="width:10%">@item.DB_Version</td>
            <td style="width:15%">@item.ExpiryDate</td>
            <td style="width:20%">
                @if (item.RequestState.Equals("Open"))
                {
                    <a href="#"><i class="btn btn-info btn-md" style="font-family:Arial">Pending</i></a>
                }
                else
                {
                    <a href="#"><i data-toggle="modal" data-target="@dataTargetCancel" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" style="font-family:Arial">Cancel</i></a>
                }
                @if (Model.ResponsibleDBs.Exists(x => x.DB_UID == item.DB_UID))
                {
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Manage", new { id = item.DB_UID })"><i class="btn btn-success btn-md" style="font-family:Arial">Manage</i></a>
                }

                @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "AssignedDatabases", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <div id="@modalID" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Do you really want to cancel the access to @item.DB_Name ?</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.DB_UID })"><i class="btn btn-success btn-md" style="font-family:Arial">Yes</i></a>
                                    <a href=""><i data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" style="font-family: Arial">No</i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a href="@Url.Action("RequestDatabase", "RequestDatabase")"><i class="btn btn-success btn-md" style="font-family:Arial">Request new</i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('body').on('click', 'a.modal-link', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $("#modal").remove();

            // Get the Details action URL
            var url = $(this).attr("href");

            //Make the Ajax call and render modal when response is available
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $(data).modal();
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I would also suggest to not use GET when deleting data. POST or DELETE are better options, as they prevent accidentally invoking the action (e.g. an error in the JavaScript could trigger the default link action)